# Activemq Not Starting with HTTP uri

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am using activemq with camel for consuming messages from a queue and send them to a http server. I am using following camel configuration :-

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders"/>
        <to uri="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <!-- <to uri="file:///Users/vinod/activemq.txt"/> -->
        <!-- <to uri="activemq:queue:sssss"/> -->
    </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?create=false"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In first block creates a route which consumer messages from `activemq:queue:Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders` queue and send them to server at `http://localhost:8080/`. The other two commented destinations are working fine, but when I start activemq with above configuration for sending messages over http, the server stops without throwing any error message. Activemq log for this is https://gist.github.com/kumar003vinod/1e5944cb246edb74c47fef7a0b433387

Please provide some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include `camel-http` and `camel-http-common` JARs in the ActiveMQ `lib/camel` directory. You may also need to include the transitive dependencies from `camel-http` in that directory so ActiveMQ has all the needed JARs in its classpath.

That would be `commons-httpclient` and `commons-codec` JARs but I think they are already included in `lib/optional`.

Comment: I have included these dependencies in pom.xml in root directory (see diff here https://gist.github.com/kumar003vinod/5d50e9c403856ce93dec192bacfab469). I am compiling project from source. After adding these if I used `mvn -Dtest=false -DfailIfNoTests=false install` command to build project, the jars for these are not created in `lib/camel`. See full pom file https://gist.github.com/kumar003vinod/f643dbfe4d6b373bfde395c607e5e945. Any hints?

Comment: I am able to compile it somehow by adding dependencies in multi pom files, but not I am getting `Ignoring converter type: org.apache.camel.component.http.RequestEntityConverter as a dependent class could not be found: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity | org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader | main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/RequestEntity` error, when activemq starts. Check https://gist.github.com/kumar003vinod/ce182c4009de1998f0927a17a5e663bd for more info.

Comment: The above problem was caused because I did not install `commons-httpclient`. After installing this it is working fine.